# Independence and conditional independence in probability

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability, independence

In a book, to explain independence and conditional independence in probability, the author gave an example that, consider the following situation:

F={ a hospital patient is smoker}

G={ a hospital patient has lung cancer}

H={ smoking causes lung cancer}.

H being true implies a relationship between F and G.

What about when H is not true? What will be the answer of this question?

Comment: I find this example confusing because the truth of $H$ does *not* by itself imply $F$ and $G$ are related.  Any relationship depends on many other factors concerning all the ways in which smoking and lung cancer would cause people to be in the hospital.  For instance, and purely hypothetically, if *not* smoking causes lung cancer, too, and at the same rates, we wouldn't expect to observe any relationship at all among $F$ and $G.$

Answer (score 0):

Let's introduce some probabilistic notation. Let $F,G$ be *events* in a certain probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$. In particular, we say that the event $F$ represents the hospital patient being a smoker, while $G$ represent the hospital patient having lung cancer.

We call the *a priori* probability of the patient having cancer $\mathbb{P}(G)$ and *a posteriori*, or conditional, probability of the patient having lung cancer knowing it's a smoker $\mathbb{P}(G\vert F)$. How are these two related? It depends on what you call *H*: wether smoking causes lung cancer or not.

If smoking caused lung cancer, then $\mathbb{P}(G\vert F)$ would be different from $\mathbb{P}(G)$. Given the nature of the subject, one would expect the former to be higher than the latter. On the other hand, if the two events were totally independent, the two probability would be exactly the same: $\mathbb{P}(G\vert F) = \mathbb{P}(G)$.

Comment: Re "If smoking caused lung cancer, then...:" how does that follow?  By ignoring the event "is in the hospital," I think you might have oversimplified the analysis and are deriving invalid conclusions.  Moreover, it *still* doesn't follow that $\Pr(G\mid F)$ would differ from $\Pr(G).$

Comment: Let me try to be more specific: first of all, what does it mean "smoking causes lung cancer"? To me, this means that the set of smokers $F$ is a subset of $G$, the set of patients with lung cancer, i.e. $F \subset G$ so that $F \cap G = F$. Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(G\vert F) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(G\cap F)}{\mathbb{P}(F)} = 1$. If smoking is independent from lung cancer, then the probability of their intersection is $\mathbb{P}(F\cap G) = \mathbb{P}(F)\mathbb{P}(G)$ so that the conditional probability is $\mathbb{P}(G\vert F) = \mathbb{P}(G)$.

Comment: In other words, you assume *all smokers in a hospital have lung cancer.*  This supposes smoking inevitably causes lung cancer and it does so before any other disease or event would put a smoker in the hospital.  Neither of those is close to being true.

Comment: True, that's the fundamental assumption of my model. A different logical interpretation of the english sentence "smoking causes lung cancer" would lead to another probability model. Does my assumption oversimplify the development of cancer in smokers and is medically inaccurate? Yes, but I don't think a scientifically detalied description of cancer is the main focus of the original question, but rather to give an intuition of how conditional probability works. The key element I wanted to underline in my answer is how a priori knowledge changes probabilities and expectations

Comment: I'm not suggesting you need a "scientifically detailed" description, but you really ought to respect the standard meaning of "cause."  In this case it means "increases the likelihood."  It does not mean -- and nobody would ever take it to mean -- "inevitably causes, to the exclusion of all other possible diseases."

Answer (score -1):

It is not an answer, but explaining the concept of logical implication may be helpful.

A implies B, or $A \Rightarrow B$, can be illustrated by this table

[image: A implies B]

where the 1s mean True and the 0 is False.
The margins of this table indicate: the column with heading $A$ means $A$ is True, the column with $\overline{A}$ means $A$ is False, the row $B$ is $B$ is True, and the row $\overline{B}$ means $B$ is False.

Now assuming that $A$ is False, the column with $\overline{A}$ has a 1 for $B$ as well as $\overline{B}$. This means that $B$ can either be True or False. There is no conclusion for $B$

However, when $A$ is True, in this column there is only a 1 for $B$. $A$ is True therefore forces $B$ to be True. This is what implication means.

But the table can also be read row-wise. When $B$ is True, in this row, there is a 1 for $A$ as well as $\overline A$. Therefore $A$ can be either True or False. One cannot draw a conclusion for $A$ when $B$ is True.

But the interesting case is the row where $B$ is False, or $\overline{B}$ is True. In this row, there is only a 1 in the column for $\overline{A}$. And this forces $A$ to be False. Or $A$ cannot be True when $B$ is False.
Hopefully, this perhaps counterintuitive case is hereby illustrated.

Comment: How does this answer the question?